# Erro Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória, alocação

Estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro no meu código:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Outra coisa é que, quando realizei a mesma operação da função `preenche` no `main`, utilizando `ficha.name` no lugar de `dados`, o sistema imprimiu apenas a primeira letra.

Por que a string não é impressa inteira? E por que eu recebo o erro quando uso a função?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct{

    char *name;
    char *phone;
    char *city;
    char *state;

}ficha_t;

void aloca (char *ptr){

    ptr = (char*) calloc (1, sizeof(char));

    if(ptr == NULL){

            puts("** Memória Insuficiênte **");
            exit(0);

    }
}

char *preenche (){

    char *dados;
    int i = 0;

    do{
        aloca(dados);
        dados[i] = getchar();
        i++;

    }while(dados[i] == '\n');

    dados[i] = '\0';

    return (dados);

}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
ficha_t ficha;

ficha.name = preenche();
printf("%s", ficha.name);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Em qual linha ocorre o segfault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem vários problemas no seu código.

O seg fault ocorre porque você esta alocando memória insuficiente para sua variável e acessa regiões de memória não alocadas.

A lógica da sua função `aloca` esta errada. Cada vez que executa `ptr = (char*) calloc (1, sizeof(char));`, um único byte é alocado e seu endereço é armazenado em `ptr`, sendo que o que você precisa, no contexto da sua utilização, é expandir a memória alocada, comportando mais caracteres.

Sua função deve utilizar o comando `realloc`, passando o tamanho correto da região de memória a ser alocada, que é o "tamanho da string + terminador da string + 1", para assim armazenar mais um byte nela. Além disso, nada garante que o gerenciador de memória não irá alterar o endereço apontado por `ptr`, sendo necessário alterar também a assinatura do comando.

```
void aloca(char **ptr) {
    *ptr = (char*)realloc(*ptr, sizeof(char) * strlen(*ptr) + 2);
    if ( *ptr == NULL ) {
        puts("** Memória Insuficiênte **");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Note que este comando serve apenas para alocar memória para strings.

O comando `realloc` re-aloca memória, copiando os valores antigos para a nova região alocada.

Note que no seu código, você não libera memória em momento algum, o que é uma má prática de programação. Em projetos maiores (ou projetos reais), além de uma má prática, pode causar problemas indesejados na sua e em outras aplicações executando na máquina.

Sobre a segunda parte da sua pergunta, não esta claro o que quer dizer. Mas pode ser que isto resolva o problema. Teste, e atualize sua pergunta com mais informações, para que eu complete minha resposta.

**Ponteiro NULL vs `realloc`**

De acordo com a [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc), uma chamada a `realloc` com o ponteiro `NULL` é equivalente a uma chamada ao `malloc`:

> If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to malloc(size), for all values of size;

Portando, desde que as implementações do `realloc` estejam corretas (e normalmente estão), pode ficar tranquilo!

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não tem problema utilizar realloc sem antes usar malloc ou calloc, como fez o bigown?

Comment: Vou adicionar a pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

As outras respostas já mostraram que o código tem alguns problemas. Vou colocar como o código pode ser mudado para funcionar. Não é a única forma de fazer, apenas uma delas:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *phone;
    char *city;
    char *state;
} ficha_t;

void aloca(char **ptr, int tamanho) {
    *ptr = (char *)realloc(*ptr, tamanho + 1);
    if(ptr == NULL){
        puts("** Memória Insuficiente **");
        exit(0);
    }
}

char *preenche() {
    char *dados = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        aloca(&dados, i);
        dados[i++] = getchar();
    } while (dados[i - 1] != '\n');
    dados[i - 1] = '\0';
    return dados;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    ficha_t ficha;
    ficha.name = preenche();
    printf("%s", ficha.name);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/D3a2Vl). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Allocatorc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Allocator.c).

Eu procurei manter mais ou menos a mesma estrutura do seu código mas ele não é a melhor forma de lidar com isto. Como provavelmente você está aprendendo e experimentando não quis te mudar sua intenção, mas lembre-se que tem formas melhores para obter o mesmo resultado. Há ineficiência em fazer múltiplas realocações. Especialmente esta forma está criando problemas de gerenciamento de memória. Em um exemplo restrito não causará problemas mas nenhum momento você está liberando a memória alocada para o membro `name`. Imagino que depois você vá mexer nos outros membros e o problema vai aumentar.

Comment: Por que a função `aloca` funciona, mesmo sem nenhum valor de retorno? É alguma peculiaridade do C que eu não conheço?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Boa pergunta. Isto foi sem querer. Mas na verdade eu estou investigando algo relacionado. Eu tive que fazer algo para funcionar e não entendi bem porque. Com o `void` não funcionava. Mas agora está retornando o que? Se eu achegar a alguma conclusão eu posto.

Comment: Segundo [essa pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4260048/520779), ele vai compilar e executar sem erro se você omitir a instrução de retorno, mas o que é retornado de fato é o que "sobrou" no registrador de retorno. Creio que - como logo antes você chamou `realloc`, que retornou um ponteiro, esse ponteiro ainda está no registrador, e por isso é retornado. Que sorte, hein? :P

Comment: @mgibsonbr resolvi o problema e consegui entender o porquê de precisar retornar. O erro do código original me fez olhar a coisa errada. É claro que tem que retornar algo, eu estou passando o endereço e quero receber o endereço, eu não estou passando o endereço p/ manipular seu conteúdo, como em outras funções seria o normal. Esta função é de gerenciamento de memória. Claro que tem como passar um ponteiro para o endereço e o Vinicius já tinha feito assim e eu não tinha percebido.

Answer (score 2):

Na funcao `preenche()` a variavel `dados` 'e um ponteiro nao inicializado.

Passas esse ponteiro para a funcao `aloca()`, mas ele nao 'e alterado: em C todos os parametros sao passados por valor.

A seguir queres usar o ponteiro nao inicializado para meter la valor. O que 'e invalido!