# Trocar vogais por "*"

Tags: c, string

Estou fazendo um programa para substituir as vogais de um frase digitada por `*` e mostrar para o usuário:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define TAM 50

int main(){
    char f[TAM];
    int t_f,n;
    printf("Digite a frase:\n");
    fgets(f,TAM,stdin);
    t_f=strlen(f);
    for(n=0;n<=t_f;n++){
        if((f[n]=='A') ||(f[n]=='a')|| (f[n]=='E')|| (f[n]=='e') || (f[n]=='I') || (f[n]=='i') || (f[n]=='O') || (f[n]=='o') || (f[n]=='U') || (f[n]=='u')){
            f[n] ='*';
        }
    }
    for(n=0;n<=t_f;n++){
        printf("Frase criptografada:%s",f[n]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Não estou entendendo porque o programa não roda e a mensagem "segmentation fault (core dumped)" está aparecendo.

Comment: Aqui no SO br tem dezenas de respostas para esse problema, dê uma olhada aqui www.shorturl.at/flPU3

Comment: Isso aqui te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52555/erro-segmentation-fault-core-dumped

Comment: Por que você faz um `for` percorrendo `n` para exibir a frase final?

Comment: Note que em C um array (que pode ser uma string: um array de caracteres seguido do caractere terminador '\0') os índices variam de 0 até o tamanho-1. Seu comando `for` considera uma posição a mais. Este é um erro mas não a causa do problema relatado que está no último printf.

Answer (score 1):

Esse trecho de código não faz sentido:

```
for(n=0;n<=t_f;n++){
    printf("Frase criptografada:%s",f[n]);
}
```

Você está percorrendo a frase inteira para exibir caractere a caractere, mas coloca como `printf` o texto "frase", indicando que quer exibir a frase inteira, adiciona `%s` para exibir uma cadeira de caracteres, mas passa como parâmetro do `printf` o valor `f[n]` que é um caractere. Em metade do código você dá indícios que quer exibir caractere por caractere e em outra metade você dá indícios que quer exibir a frase inteira. No fim, misturou tudo.

Para exibir o resultado, basta fazer:

```
printf("Frase criptografada: %s", f);
```

Pois `f` já é uma sequência de caracteres.

Comment: Entendi. Muito Obrigada :)